# Drop down source issues for Apex Form

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-apex, apex, selectlist

I have a table I created to use as the source for the of dropdowns of a form. The goal is to have only what possible options are available for the Department code based on who the owner is. I got the scrap owner to display correctly but unfortunately I have not been able for the department code to show up. No options are able to pop up. This is what my code looks like:

```
    Select DEPT_CODE, DEPT_CODE as Value From Degrade_Robots
    WHERE SO_NAME = :P7_SCRAP_OWNER

    group by DEPT_CODE

    order by DEPT_CODE
```

My table is set up like:
[image]

Comment: Are you really using Oracle Apex with MySQL database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't aggregating anything; don't use `group by` but `distinct`.

```
select distinct
       dept_code as display_value,
       dept_code as return_value
from degrade_robots
where so_name = :P7_SCRAP_OWNER
order by dept_code;
```

As you don't see anything in the list, I presume that's because you *forgot* to mention `P7_SCRAP_OWNER` item in Select List's LoV **Parent Item(s)** property.

[image]